# string replacement in javascript when contains `{}`

Tags: javascript

I use the templates and javascript to generate the htmls for an json data, this is the tempalte:

```
    <div id="template">
        <div class="iwContainer">
            <div class="iwHeaderContainer">
                <div class="iw-title-container">
                    <span class="titleText">${name}</span> <a target="_blank" href="detail?fid=${id}" class="titleLink">Detail</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="iwRichContainer">
                <div class="iw-g-font">Address：${address}</div>
            </div>
            @{setsearchTemplate}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Js:

```
buildInfoContent : function(item) {
    var tmp = $("#template").html();
    if (tmp) {
        tmp = tmp.replace(/\$\{(\w*)\}/g, function(m, key) {
            return item.hasOwnProperty(key) ? item[key] : "";
        });
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

And I call it:

```
buildInfoContent({name:'name',id:2,address:'address'});
```

And all of the palcehodler are replaced but the `${id}`.

Through firebug I found that the temlate is something like this:

```
.........<span class="titleText">${name}</span> <a target="_blank" href="detail?fid=$%7bid%7d" class="titleLink">Detail</a>.......
```

So the `id` is not replaced, how to fixe it?

Comment: It runs fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/QH8gG/

Comment: :(. I test no another machine, it works, but not on my own machine.

Comment: So, any idea to change the `{ }` to `other character`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your browser is encoding your `{}` characters. You'll have to account for that in your regexp...

This is untested but...
`/\$(\{|%7b)(\w*)(\}|%7d)/`

This should do it, or something very similar...The idea is their though. Sometimes browsers do funky things with special characters.

**EDIT:** To match the key (the middle matched group), try using the 3rd argument passed to your callback, like in this example : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A5fnA/1/)

Comment: Thanks, I use your regexp and  I use this function :`function(m, key) {key=RegExp.$2;
            return item.hasOwnProperty(key) ? item[key] : "";
        }`  I wonder if this contains any potential problems?

Comment: You should be able to just copy the regex above over the current regex youre using, you shouldn't have to change any other code.

Comment: No, without change other code, the `key` will be `{` not the property name.

Comment: I gotcha you are right, you want the second matched group of the 3.

Comment: I am goint to be crazy, the `Regexp.$2` return empty in IE.